# Python and Pip have different paths

Tags: python, pip

Trying to run my code i get `module not found` and trying install gives already exists

i found that running
which python3 points to

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

which pip3  gives

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
```

which pip gives

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip
```

I am using MacOS M1 .

Comment: Uninstall `pip` using `brew` and install `python` using `brew`. After that, use `python` to install `pip`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, so what's your question exactly? Please read [ask]. It's actually possible for Python and pip to have different paths and still be connected. (That is to say, that's not a problem in itself.) Are you sure you're running your code and the install with the same version of Python? To be sure, try running the command `python3 x.py`, where `x.py` is the path to your script, and `python3 -m pip install mod`, where `mod` is the module you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` points to python2 pip. You have python2 installed by running `python` in your terminal.

`pip3` is used to install to `python3` and they appear to be installed correctly and in the same place per your post.

So all you need to do is run either `python3 -m pip install <whatever_you_want>` OR `pip3 install <whatever_you_want>` and in both cases that will work.

Once you do that when run your program make sure you run it via `python3 my_program.py` and NOT `python my_program.py`. Similarly to play with the imports using the console just run `python3` and not `python`. Assuming you do this correctly you should be fine.